# How to fix " SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import " in vue3 with webpack 5 ,sass loader12

Tags: webpack, sass, vuejs3, sass-loader

I am trying to import scss file from assets to components , getting error show that ,

@import "@/assets/scss/_globvar.scss";

this the error i am getting

**" Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import "**

[image]

files structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Prefix path `~` tells webpack to search through node_modules. [link](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#resolving-import-at-rules)

You may need to use `relative path` or `path alias`

Comment: Already i used this " @import "~/assets/scss/_globvar.scss " , still get same error

Comment: `@import ../../assets/scss/_globvar.scss` for `relative path`, `@import` prefix `~` will  search in the `node_modules` folder. In most cases, `@` is an alias for the `src` folder